# cakephp2.x component not working

Tags: cakephp, components

i create my component like this

```
<?php
class UtilComponent extends Object
{
   function strip_and_clean( $id, $array) {
      $id = intval($id);
     if( $id < 0 || $id >= count($array) ) {
        $id = 0;
     }
      return $id;
   }
}
```

and use it like this

```
var $name = 'Books';
    var $uses = array();
    var $components = array('Util');
    public function index($id = 0){
        $this -> set('page_heading','Packt Book Store');
        $book=array(
            '0'=>array(
                'bookTitle'    =>'Object Oriented Programming with PHP5',
                'author'       =>'Hasin Hayder',
                'isbn'         => '1847192564',
            'releaseDate' => 'December 2007'
                ),
            '1'=>array(
                'bookTitle'    =>'Building Websites with Joomla! v1.0',
                'author'       =>'Hagen Graf',
                'isbn'         => '1904811949',
            'releaseDate' => 'March 2006'
                ),
            );
        $id = $this->Util->strip_and_clean( $id, $book);
        $this->set('book',$book[$id]);
        $this->pageTitle='Welcome to the Packt Book Store!';
    }
```

but i got this error

`**call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'UtilComponent' does not have a method 'initialize' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 130]**

Comment: Try to print_r($id); and show me...

Comment: try to print before line $id = $this->Util->strip_and_clean( $id, $book); and after this also and give exit;  show to us.

Answer (score 7):

I believe a component should extend `Component` not `Object`:

```
class UtilComponent extends Component 
{

}
```

The component will then inherit the `initialize()` method.

Comment: we can use object also .. class UtilComponent extends object

Comment: @Learner The `Component` class does extend `Object`, but the `initialize()` method gets defined in `Component`. This seems to be the result of the error. See http://api20.cakephp.org/class/component

Comment: right, thanx.also the $this->set('book',$book[$id]); couse another problem Undefined variable:bookTitle,author, isbn,releaseDate.why?

Comment: I am using cake 1.3 ,, i am using object only. and i am able to use my component in controllers,, will you please specify with initialize word...

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: bookTitle [APP\View\Books\index.ctp, line 3]

Comment: $book=array(
   '0'=>array(
    'bookTitle'    =>'Object Oriented Programming with PHP5',
    'author'       =>'Hasin Hayder',
    'isbn'         => '1847192564',
                'releaseDate' => 'December 2007'
    ),
   '1'=>array(
    'bookTitle'    =>'Building Websites with Joomla! v1.0',
    'author'       =>'Hagen Graf',
    'isbn'         => '1904811949',
                'releaseDate' => 'March 2006'
    ),
   );

Comment: @paynestrike That error is in your view. You have not set the variable `bookTitle` in the controller, just the array `book`, but you are referencing `$bookTitle` at line 3 in the view file. Try using `$book['bookTitle']` instead.

Comment: <h2><?php echo $page_heading; ?></h2>
    <dl>
    <lh><?php echo $bookTitle; ?></lh>
    <dt>Author:</dt><dd><?php echo $author; ?></dd>
    <dt>ISBN:</dt><dd><?php echo $isbn; ?></dd>
    <dt>Release Date:</dt><dd><?php echo $releaseDate; ?></dd>
    </dl>

Comment: Undefined variable: book [APP\View\Books\index.ctp, line 3]

Comment: @DougOwings Is right.. i think paynestrike is useless coder ,, he didn't tried to echo error in his code.. he just posted over here...

Comment: that hurts dude,i did the var_dump($book[$id]),and it seems alright.i use the $book[$id] is cakephp1.3 works,but when use 2.0 not work.so how my suppose to know that

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar issue.

Apart from the error message **... does not have a method 'initialize' ...**, one more message was there **... does not have a method 'startup' ...**.

The issue was I created the component file inside the `Controller` directory instead of `Controller/Component`.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue like

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'ImageComponent' does not have a method 'initialize' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 128]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'ImageComponent' does not have a method 'beforeRender' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 128]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'ImageComponent' does not have a method 'shutdown' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 128]

**Solution is :**

Add Image component into controller/component then

change **class ImageComponent extends object  { ... }**

with **class ImageComponent extends Component  { ... }**